# Serializing Object whose type is not known at compile time

Tags: c#, serialization

I got a list of models which may vary and their type cannot be known at compile time. The only options I have to implement this collection is either by making a `List<Object>` or `List<dynamic>` (I know the first one is faster and better). The problem is that when trying to serialize this collection, the .Net's `XmlSerializer` throws an exception saying that "Data whose type is not known at compile time cannot be serialized". The question is, according to this exception, is it possible at all to do this and if yes how can this be done efficiently.

Update:

Binary serialization is not an option here (can't use it)

Comment: If you are open to use json, Json.Net can do it.

Comment: @EZI: I think that would cause exactly the same problem cause the objects must be automatically unboxed. Is that capable of doing so?

Comment: No need to discuss about it. It is a one-line code. Try it `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: the earlier comments below refer to a different solution from an earlier version of the question.)

Have you tried this?

```
var types = theList.Select(o => o.GetType()).Distinct().ToArray();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<object>), types);
...
```

Deserialization will be harder, of course; you'll need to parse the necessary types out of the XML and then use reflection to get the type objects into an array so you can instantiate the XmlSerializer.  You could simplify that somewhat by packaging the XML with some metadata that lists the necessary types.

Comment: This can't be done, if you make a base class, the extended classes are of unknown type to the "XmlSerializer" because their data is different from their base. and I tried it before it will be useless.

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't be done; you just have to make separate serializers for the derived classes.

Comment: This is very loosely coupled application, you can never know what type is going there, some guy may add a new model the next hour :D, this is an engine on my side, but I can't know what models will be serialized and I really need to serialize Unknown types like objects

Comment: @Tom okay, I will add another idea to the answer.

Comment: @Tom I didn't realize you were trying to serialize the whole collection.  How are you instantiating the XmlSerializer?  Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: Thanks Phoog but please keep in mind that the solution must support DeSerialization too. Serializing can be done by Reflections but DeSerializing would be very messy.

Comment: if you are after the `typeof` it is `typeof(List<Object>)`

Comment: I am not after the typeof; I am after the other arguments you're using.

Comment: Ok Phoog here you are: `new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Object>)).Serialize(Mems, Collection);` and Collection is of type `List<Object>` and Mems is `MemeoryStream`

Comment: @Tom please see the new answer.  Tell the XmlSerializer about the types being serialized by passing them in via its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the list item after item, like:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
        var list = new List<object>() 
        {
            new ModelA() { Foo = 9 },
            new ModelB() { Bar = "some string" }
        };

        writer.WriteStartElement("root");
        list.ForEach(x => ToXml(x, writer));
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream));
        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ToXml(object obj, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you can probably add a simple pool of XmlSerializer with one serializer per target type

Comment: How would you deserialize this?